# How to adjust apps UI to different screen size of iPhone models?

Tags: swift, storyboard, constraints, screen-size

I find one solution is using extension to detect current iPhone model at runtime; however, it indeed involves massive of changes from my current code and design (i.e. change a lot of buttons location and size in single storyboard, a lot of constraints need to be updated as well etc). Are there any better solutions than this one? Thank you!

Comment: Could you add *one specific* issue - one that can be replicated? As it is, I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. I've done auto layout constraints  - both in code and storyboard - for iPad and iPhone with no problems. The only time I actually "change" constraints is (a) when I desire a different layout for landscape versus portrait and then (b) I deactivate/activate an array of them. I see no need to check iPhone models or screen sizes. But you may have that need. A specific example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I always vote for creating constraints in IB as possible as you can , because it cuts time less than in code as you'll see the result instantly and do constraints fastly , the tip is to create it proportional as much as you can , look to the current device you do the constraints with as a generic device for example instead of setting a static height like 200 , look to design scale an make it proportional say 0.2 of screen height , same for width , you can make it also with origin constraints like top , leading but it needs some advanced constraints , make use of size classes and adaptive layout , also font adjustment , if all that fails hook the constraint and play with it in code